# Multithreading - Node js efficiency vs Apache

Tags: node.js, multithreading, apache, event-loop

As I understood, Node js handles threads internally. So, if an HTTP request comes in, and some intensive I/O operation is required, node spawns another thread that handles the I/O operation, and in the meantime continues listening to incoming HTTP requests in its main thread. In PHP running on Apache, on the other hand, each HTTP request gets its own thread that handles it. All in all, in both cases you have 2 threads running, right? So what is the performance gain of node when compared to Apache?

Comment: NodeJS uses async/io, you don't pay for a context switch - you could say that the overhead is "batched". The threads are long living.

Answer (score 0):

In event based servers, like node or most modern Java EE servers, a single (or few threads) take turns servicing work on 1 thread for many otherwise unrelated client connections.   How this sharing/cooperation is managed can take many forms (e.g. couroutines in some languages, closely managed state machines and continuation processing in some servers), but the net gains are:

- no context switching as different threads spring back to life
- no/little thread synchronization needed
- much greater vertical scalability

Some downsides are:

- more complicated to develop for
- risk that some bad code/extension can stall many thousands of requests